# Why doesn't Python 3 find installed packages (e.g. BeautifulSoup4)?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip

Using Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5 I get import errors for some packages, e.g. 'BeautifulSoup4' or 'requests'. Both libraries are installed from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -E "python3-req|python3-bs"
python3-bs4                         install
python3-requests                    install
```

Yet I get "ImportError: no module named 'bs4'/'requests'".

```
$ python3 -c "import bs4"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Only when I (additionally!) install those libraries via pip3 it works. The documentation of BeautifulSoup says to install it as "python3-bs4" via apt. Why does it only work with the pip3 method? What's the purpose of the python3-bs4/python3-requests packages?

Comment: You probably have two Python 3 versions.  You installed bs4 on the wrong Python version but `pip3` is in the correct environment version you are using

Comment: I would recommend you to install Python packages using `pip`, not using your operating system’s package manager.

Comment: @poke That's dubious advice. There are situations where `pip` is certainly the right choice, but this depends on a large number of factors. Certainly if you are working towards creating a Debian-compatible package of your own, you definitely want to make sure you are developing against the Debian versions of your dependencies.

Comment: @Simon: I am not able to see more than one python3 versions on my system. I have the "python3" and the "python3.5" package installed. But the "python3" package is just some kind of wrapper package that delivers python3.5 as a dependency.

Comment: I doubt that very much.  How did you come to that conclusion?  Also did you install either of them?

Comment: @AndreasN: I think Simon is absolutely correct. Run `python3 -V` to see what python version it is pointing to. It will probably be `python3.4`, not `python3.5`. Then run `pip3 -V` to see what python's `pip` it is pointing to. You should also have both `pip3.4` and `pip3.5` commands available that will list you the packages installed for `python3.4` and `python3.5`, respectively. I would rather seek for ways to remove the older python3 and set the newer one as the default one to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I checked the versions. It's `Python 3.5.2` and `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)`. I don't have any executables by name `python3.4` or `pip3.4` on my system.

Comment: Also check `which python3` and `which pip3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.

I'm still not quite sure what was the exact problem, but I suspect that pip3 and apt confused each other about what was actually installed. pip3 also listed several python packages which were installed via `apt`.

I removed/purged everything via apt that was recognized by `pip3 list` and also purged pip3. Then I `apt install --reinstall` the packages that gave me trouble previously: python3-bs4 and python3-requests. The `requests` library still didn't work because it missed the packages `python3-six`, `python3-chardet` and `python3-urllib3` which where reported as already installed by apt. A `apt install --reinstall` fixed this as well. And then it worked!